# How to get max value with various conditions from a single MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have table with a bunch of (machine id) `mid`'s and (sensor id) `sid`'s, and their corresponding (values) `v`'s. Needless to say the `id` column is a unique row number. *(**NB:** There are other columns in the table, and not all `mid`'s have the same `sid`'s)*

**Current Table:**

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
|  id  |  mid  |  sid  |  v  |      timestamp      |
+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
|  51  |  10   |   1   |  40 |  2015/5/1 11:56:01  |
|  52  |  10   |   2   |  39 |  2015/5/1 11:56:25  |
|  53  |  10   |   2   |  40 |  2015/5/1 11:56:42  |
|  54  |  11   |   1   |  50 |  2015/5/1 11:57:52  |
|  55  |  11   |   2   |  18 |  2015/5/1 11:58:41  |
|  56  |  11   |   2   |  19 |  2015/5/1 11:58:59  |
|  57  |  11   |   3   |  58 |  2015/5/1 11:59:01  |
|  58  |  11   |   3   |  65 |  2015/5/1 11:59:29  |
+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
```

**Q:** How would I get the `MAX(v)`for each `sid` for each `mid`?

**Expected Output:**

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
|  id  |  mid  |  sid  |  v  |      timestamp      |
+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
|  51  |  10   |   1   |  40 |  2015/5/1 11:56:01  |
|  53  |  10   |   2   |  40 |  2015/5/1 11:56:42  |
|  54  |  11   |   1   |  50 |  2015/5/1 11:57:52  |
|  56  |  11   |   2   |  19 |  2015/5/1 11:58:59  |
|  58  |  11   |   3   |  65 |  2015/5/1 11:59:29  |
+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
```

The expected output is to obtain the whole row with all the (single) max `v`alue for all the `sid`s in all the `mid`s.

**Addendum:**

Due to a very big table, I need to place boundaries with dates. For the sample above the two boundary dates should be `2015/05/01 00:00:00` (1st of May'15) till `2015/05/02 00:00:00` (2nd of May'15). **Q:** How could I add this date boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Find the max v in subquery for each combination of mid, sid and then join it with your original table to get the desired result.

```
select *
from your_table t
join (
    select mid, sid, max(v) as v
    from your_table
    group by mid, sid
) t2 using (mid, sid, v);
```

Note here that if there are multiple rows with same sid, mid and v, it will return all of them.

As mentioned in the comments, since you have an id column, you can include that in limited correlated query like this:

```
select *
from your_table t1
where id = (select id
            from your_table t2
            where t1.mid = t2.mid
            and t1.sid = t2.sid
            order by v desc, id desc
            limit 1
            );
```

This will give you one single row per mid, sid combination with max v (and latest id in case of ties).

Comment: _Note here that if there are multiple rows with same sid, mid and v, it will return all of them._ How could I make it so that it just returns one?

Comment: @3kstc - Which one do you want to return? Is there an id column - if yes perhaps max(id) to break the ties..?

Comment: Yes there is an id column, how would I incorporate that?

Comment: @3kstc - Updated with alternate solution.

Comment: Okay, yours gets rid of duplicates in the case where you have two rows with the same mid, sid, and v.  Nice job!

Comment: @GurwinderSingh, To confirm `t1` and `t2`are referring to the same table `your_table` ?

Comment: @3kstc - That's correct. t1 and t2 are aliases for the same table

Comment: @GurwinderSingh, how can I put date boundaries into the query? I tried but it didn't work! :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX()` function with `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT id,  mid,  sid, MAX(v) AS v, `timestamp` 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY mid,  sid;
```

This returns rows with maximum values of `v` for each combination of `mid` and `sid`.